# Python terminate multiprocessing and gui process gracefully

Tags: python, multiprocessing, glade

I am using glade as my gui and creating a process to run my gui in. This app will open a socket when 'on' is clicked. When i press 'send', it will send whatever is in an textfield to the socket. The socket receives this data and sends it back. The problem is after i send data to the socket the thread doesn't terminate. Also after i close my gui it calls a sys.exit() but also leaves a process and doesn't terminate. I believe the error is in how i am implementing my processes or all my processing in general. Can anyone shine some light on this? It also relates to my last post as well. Thanks

main.py

// Main thread that create a new process for my gui and displays it

```
import socket, thread, gtk, Handler, sys, os, multiprocessing 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)  


if __name__ == '__main__':

    builder = gtk.Builder()
    #32bit template.glade 64bit template-2.22
    # @todo add switching between architectures
    #
    builder.add_from_file("template/template-2.22.glade")
    builder.connect_signals(Handler.Handler(builder))
    window = builder.get_object("window1")
    window.show_all()
    try:
        p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=gtk.main())
        p.start()

    except:
            print "Error Starting new Thread"
```

handler.py

// Handler for gtk glade signals, creates new threads and handles button and stuff

```
import thread, threading, os, server, client,multiprocessing, time
import sys, gtk


class Handler(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    myobject = ''

    def __init__(self,object1):
        #Getting glade builder
        self.myobject = object1
        '''
        Constructor
        '''

    def clickme(self,value):

        myserver = server.Server()
        try:
            p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=myserver.run)
            p.start()

        except:
            pass

    def sendmessage(self,value):
        text = self.myobject.get_object('entry1').get_text()
        print text
        msg = client.MyClass()
        p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=msg.run,args=([text]))
        p.start()
```

server.py

// Opens a socket and listens for incoming data and sends it back

```
import socket,multiprocessing, gtk, sys

class Server:
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''

    def run(self):

        try:
            while 1:
                HOST = 'localhost'                 # Symbolic name meaning the local host
                PORT = 50006              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
                s.bind((HOST, PORT))
                s.listen(5)
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                print 'Connected by', addr
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        conn.close()
                        sys.exit()
                        break
                    elif data != '':
                        conn.sendall(data)
                        break

            print "Closing"    
            #conn.close()
        finally:
            print "End"
            pass
```

client.py

// Sends whatever is inside text area to socket

```
import time

class MyClass:
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
    def run(self,text):
        try:
            import socket
            HOST = 'localhost'    # The localhost
            PORT = 50006             # The same port as used by the server
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))
            s.send(text)
            data = s.recv(1024)

            while 1:
                if data != '':
                    print 'Received', repr(data)
                    break
        finally:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just wrong:

```
p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=gtk.main())
p.start()
```

First, you can't start the gtk main loop in a subprocess, even if you did it rigth. Fortunately the process never really tries to start `main` as you **call** `gtk.main()`, which will block until the main loop exits and then return `None`. So what you're actually doing is:

```
gtk.main()
p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=None)
p.start()
```

Througout the rest of your code you keep creating new processes and then forgetting about them. If you would keep a reference to them, you could at least try to send the `TERM` signal to them to shut them down (using `Process.terminate`, or set the [`daemon`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) flag). If you want to shut down the subprocess cleanly, you either need to [handle that signal](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal) in the subprocess, or use other IPC mechanisms to get it to shut down cleanly (like `mutliprocessing.Event`, ...).

Then there is this:

```
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    conn.close()
                    sys.exit()
                    break
                elif data != '':
                    conn.sendall(data)
                    break
```

This while loop will never loop (unless `recv` magically returns something else then a string). The first execution path ends with `sys.exit()` (taking the whole server down - the break is unreachable), the second ends with `break`, so the loop is useless.

A few lines below you have the exact opposite:

```
        data = s.recv(1024)
        while 1:
            if data != '':
                print 'Received', repr(data)
                break
```

Unless `data` was `''` in the first line, this will be an endless loop, as `data`'s value won't change anymore.

Generally you don't really need multiprocessing for most of this. Starting a server in a different process may be ok if if has to do a lot of work, but spawing a subprocess just to send some data is overkill. Sending and receiving using sockets are IO bound, using threading here would be more reasonable.

You have two classes (`Server` and `Handler`) which have only two methods, one of which is `__init__`, and the other one is only used as target for a subprocess:

```
    myserver = server.Server()
    try:
        p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=myserver.run)
```

and:

```
    msg = client.MyClass()
    p =  multiprocessing.Process(target=msg.run,args=([text]))
```

That's a sign that these shouldn't be classes but functions.